# JSON object causing exception with Rails JSON.decode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, itunes

The JSON object below causes `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode` to throw the exception below. What causes this?

Exception:

```
795: unexpected token at ''
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/multi_json-1.9.2/lib/multi_json/adapters/json_common.rb:16:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/multi_json-1.9.2/lib/multi_json/adapter.rb:20:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/multi_json-1.9.2/lib/multi_json.rb:121:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/json/decoding.rb:15:in `decode'
```

JSON object (from https://itunes.apple.com/us/lookup?id=972909677):

```
{
 "resultCount":1,
 "results": [
{"artistViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/twitter-inc./id296415947?uo=4", "artworkUrl60":"http://is2.mzstatic.com/image/pf/us/r30/Purple5/v4/08/c5/cf/08c5cf4e-876f-8518-d23e-6d2e4b24694b/AppIcon60x60_U00402x.png", 
"screenshotUrls":["http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple3/v4/13/a1/86/13a18611-ba42-d9fe-38a2-3c5b03db7543/screen1136x1136.jpeg", "http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple3/v4/f3/4c/68/f34c68fe-7284-d094-00ef-49bd66e53851/screen1136x1136.jpeg", "http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple3/v4/9c/1a/c3/9c1ac3c8-cf2c-99cf-87f4-beb9d0962e83/screen1136x1136.jpeg", "http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple6/v4/12/25/a5/1225a5e4-224f-04c6-6ca9-350b4d348aaa/screen1136x1136.jpeg"], "ipadScreenshotUrls":[], "artworkUrl512":"http://is5.mzstatic.com/image/pf/us/r30/Purple3/v4/23/52/7b/23527b98-654b-4dab-9352-4359f1a5e541/mzl.icaayech.jpg", "kind":"software", "features":[], 
"supportedDevices":["iPadFourthGen4G", "iPhone6", "iPad23G", "iPhone5s", "iPadMini", "iPhone6Plus", "iPad2Wifi", "iPhone4S", "iPhone5", "iPadFourthGen", "iPhone4", "iPodTouchFifthGen", "iPadThirdGen", "iPadThirdGen4G", "iPadMini4G", "iPhone5c"], "advisories":[], "isGameCenterEnabled":false, "trackCensoredName":"Periscope", "trackViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/periscope/id972909677?mt=8&uo=4", "contentAdvisoryRating":"4+", "artworkUrl100":"http://is5.mzstatic.com/image/pf/us/r30/Purple3/v4/23/52/7b/23527b98-654b-4dab-9352-4359f1a5e541/mzl.icaayech.jpg", "languageCodesISO2A":["NB", "CA", "CS", "DA", "NL", "EN", "FR", "DE", "EL", "ID", "IT", "JA", "KO", "NN", "PL", "PT", "RU", "ZH", "ES", "SV", "ZH", "TR", "UK", "VI"], "fileSizeBytes":"15090739", "sellerUrl":"https://periscope.tv", "averageUserRatingForCurrentVersion":3.5, "userRatingCountForCurrentVersion":166, "trackContentRating":"4+", "currency":"USD", "wrapperType":"software", "version":"1.0.2", 
"description":"Periscope lets you broadcast live video to the world. Going live will instantly notify your followers who can join, comment and send you hearts in real time. The more hearts you get, the higher they flutter on the screen.\n\nOther features:\n[+] REPLAY: When your broadcast is over, you can make it available for replay so viewers can watch later. Viewers can replay your broadcast with comments and hearts to relive the full experience. Replays currently last 24 hours. You can delete your replay at any time.\n[+] PRIVATE: If you want to broadcast to specific people, press the lock icon before going live and choose who you want to invite to your broadcast. \n[+] TWITTER: You can choose to share your Periscope broadcasts on Twitter by tapping the bird icon before you start broadcasting. When you go live, you’ll tweet a link so that your Twitter followers can watch on the web (or in the app)\n[+] MANAGE NOTIFICATIONS: Periscope will suggest people for you to follow based on your Twitter network. You can always follow new people, or unfollow them if you don’t want to be notified when they go live. You can also adjust notification preferences in Periscope Settings (in Profile)\n[+] HEARTS: Periscope keeps track of how many hearts you get from your viewers. The more hearts, the higher you get in the “Most Loved” list.", "artistId":296415947, "artistName":"Twitter, Inc.", "genres":["Social Networking"], "price":0.00, "bundleId":"com.bountylabs.periscope", "genreIds":["6005"], "releaseDate":"2015-03-26T07:01:50Z", "sellerName":"Twitter, Inc.", "trackName":"Periscope", "trackId":972909677, "primaryGenreName":"Social Networking", "primaryGenreId":6005, 
"releaseNotes":"- New ‘Global’ section added to Periscope that lists the most recent, live broadcasts from around the world. Your home feed will only show live broadcasts and replays tailored to you.\n- A new “Follower Only” mode is available before starting your broadcast. If you turn this on, only viewers that YOU follow can comment in your broadcast.\n- Users who are verified are marked by the classic Twitter Verified badge you’re used to seeing.\n- Major scrolling performance improvements. This will feel silky and smooth compared to the last version!\n- You can block users more easily (tap on a comment to present the option to block)\n- Fixed a bug where viewers & broadcasters would sometimes stop seeing comments and hearts.\n- Fixed a caching issue where the wrong Profile image would get displayed for a user\n- Fixed a bug where some iOS 7 users couldn’t watch broadcasts with kajillions of viewers", "minimumOsVersion":"7.1", "formattedPrice":"Free", "userRatingCount":949, "averageUserRating":3.5}]
}
```

Request code:

```
    id_string = a.join ','

    # Make request to iTunes API
    uri = URI.parse itunes_url + id_string
    http = Net::HTTP.new uri.host, uri.port
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
    resp = http.request req

    # JSON string -> Hash
    logger.info "+++ Decoding #{uri}"
    resp_hash = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode resp.body.strip
```

Output of `resp.body.strip`:

```
]P?NA
     ??+??@
?u)S ??CΞ/???n?#?)ʿ?="
?m?gF?b??B"x?Ї]?`Nx5z?G+Éo{?Lj?d7|???~?3)???????u?RK?@?????W[8?%r:+?V??Z@+LX?L?TcB?0?e?U?ZQ^Z??ק?-??5BNsj?A?yO
?i?5Н$ʩV-t?sj??_~?nݭ?                                                                                         u?'?l??x
9?3
```

Comment: Are you sure that's a JSON object? It looks like an object literal/hash. Are you calling `decode` manually, and if so, maybe the JSON has already been parsed?

Comment: @Yaniv Sorry yes it's not a JSON object yet; it's a JSON string that needs to get decoded into a JSON object. It's the return value from https://itunes.apple.com/us/lookup?id=972909677

Comment: How are you getting it from itunes?

Comment: @Yaniv Just making a request to itunes.apple.com/us/lookup?id=972909677 from Rails ... is this what you mean? And if it is, the question is now updated the request code.

Comment: I just tried it in Pry and everything worked fine for me... Can you add what your `resp.body.strip` looks like?

Comment: @Yaniv Interesting ... updated the question with the output from resp.body.strip. Seems like an issue with a garbled response?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76213/discussion-between-yaniv-and-crashalot).

Comment: I would double check id string and url. When I straight up copied the URL from the apple page, everything worked fine. You might be making a request to the wrong URL.

Comment: @Yaniv I just went to the chat room. Are you still there?

Comment: FWIW, out of curiosity I chucked the json into jsonLint.com which gave it a tick.